# How to protected specific GET routes with WP REST API OAUTH authentication

Tags: php, wordpress, rest, oauth

I have a new *WordPress* project and I am using only two plugins, **WP REST API** and **WP REST API - OAuth 1.0a Server**. For default, only some routes are protected by authentication and I want to protect some specific routes. For example, the **GET** route *http://localhost:8080/wp-json/wp/v2/posts* should be protected and require the authentication, but it is not.

How do I protect it using these two plugins? I have read the entire documentation but I did not found it.

Answer (score 1):

I have also been looking into this, using same plugins as well. Only solution I have so far found is through using the 'iThemes Security' plugin and setting WordPress Tweaks > REST API select field to 'Restricted Access'.
Then only OAuth 1 authenticated GET requests will return data, any un-authenicated GET requests will not return data. A 500 internal server error status code is the response.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Capability Manager Enhanced Plugin(https://wordpress.org/plugins/capability-manager-enhanced/) and create a user and give them the access to specific post type using CME plugin . If you want to give different access to different post type then you need to set the "capability" field to a different name other than the "post" which is default value.

Now only that user can access the rest api.